# Reserving ID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, asynchronous, database-design, transactions, message-queue

I have a problem in my architecture.

I need to create a record inside MySQL database but only after the asynchronous job ending. This job can take several seconds up to minutes.

I do need to send back to user in HTTP response the ID during the trigger of this asynchronous operation. But I don't have this ID yet because is auto incremented by MySQL.

My idea was to reserve an ID in table and after the async operation insert the record in this ID.

Obs: I can't use Transaction and then Rollback because is not reliable during a MySQL restart.

**EDIT**: There are too many records being inserted per second.

Comment: Can you create the row with default values, and have the async job fill it in? Add an `active` column to the table to indicate whether the row has valid data in it.

Comment: This is a good use case for an UUID mey

Comment: Create the row with default values seems a option. But I cannot confirm for now. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Are you using AJAX? Have the async operation do the INSERT and get the id, then return it in the AJAX response.

Plan B:

Create the row, but with mostly NULLs.  Get its inserted id.  Pass that to the async job.  The job can then `UPDATE` the row with that specific id.  Later, you  can ignore any rows with NULL in some critical column, implying that something crashed or has not yet finished.

Plan C:

It is pretty simple to create a "sequence" table with one row with 2 columns.  It effectively lets you generate numbers.  (MariaDB has a "sequence" pseudo-table to make that even easier.)

Comment: Plan B seems better. Plan A seems is not viable. Can you tell me about Plan C?

Comment: @MarloneLima - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#sequence